# How to remove the value of my li tag without affecting my span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove the value inside of my li tag(Profile, Event, Photos, Notification) without affecting the span tag once i click the menu .. pls.. need some helping hand here.. Thank You!!

```html
<nav class="nav navi-tag">
            <ul class="font">
                <a><li data-button = "btn-navbar" id = "btn1"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>Profile</li></a>
                <a><li data-button = "btn-navbar" id = "btn2"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Events</li></a>
                <a><li data-button = "btn-navbar" id = "btn3"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>Photos</li></a>
                <a><li data-button = "btn-navbar" id = "btn4"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Notification</li></a>
            </ul>
            <div class = "font handle">Menu</div>
        </nav>
```

my JS

```
 $('.handle').click(function() {
          $nav.each(function() {
          ss = $(this).text();
          xx = $('nav ul a li').html().replace(ss, "");
          alert(xx);
          });
```

Comment: anchor cannot be an immediate child of ul

Comment: Get all child nodes of your `<li>`. Filter for `.nodeType === 3` (Text nodes). Remove these nodes.

Comment: Toggle a class and use css. Please also read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle of what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/3qypL8gb/

I removed your `<a>` tags because as someone said in the comments they cannot be direct child of a `<ul>` and you weren't doing anything with them anyway.

I took advantage of how the words you wanted to remove were the last text in the `<li>`. I stored the length of the html and then stored the length of the text and made a substring of the html.length - text.length.

I then replaced the `<li>` html with that new substring.